# Wrong Group counter showing on Contact tab

Tags: smartgroups

It can be reproduced in dmaster following the next steps:

1. Go into [dmaster](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/)
2. Create a Smart Group
3. Add "Manually" a Contact in the Smart Group
4. Go to the Contact (the counter in the Group Tab shows a number, p.ex. 0)
5. Access to the Group Tab
6. Now the counter has been updated into 1 because the contact is in a Group

It's a normal behaviour? Or can it be considered as a bug?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Reloading the contact page - after the groups tab has been selected (results in the same behaviour) - Does this suggest it's not an issue with the cache, and perhaps with how the groups are being calculated initially?

Comment: afaik smart groups get recalculated when you click on the Group Tab so it would make sense if that is when you are saying the number goes up

Comment: Ok. So this can be considered a little bug. I'll try to report to the lab. Thanks

Comment: It may be a problem of Smart Group Updating time : see related smartgroups posts